# emacs windows run python program in current buffer and display the output on output window

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I use the Python-mode (not the default one comes with emacs 23).

I could not execute the python program currently loaded in emacs.

I am getting "Symbol's function definition is void: smart-operator-mode-on" error.

Any clue or any tips makes a python program and it can be run on emacs and show the result output window?

Here the **emacs error report**.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function smart-operator-mode-on)
     (smart-operator-mode-on)
     (lambda nil (set-variable (quote py-indent-offset) 4) 
      (set-variable (quote indent-tabs-mode) nil) (define-key py-mode-map (kbd "RET")  (quote newline-and-indent)) (smart-operator-mode-on))()
      run-hooks(python-mode-hook)
     (if python-mode-hook (run-hooks (quote python-mode-hook)) (run-hooks (quote py-mode-hook)))   python-mode()
```

**My init_python.el script**

```
 (autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
 (add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))

  (require 'python-mode)
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
(set-variable 'py-indent-offset 4)
;(set-variable 'py-smart-indentation nil)
(set-variable 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
(define-key py-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
;(define-key py-mode-map [tab] 'yas/expand)
;(setq yas/after-exit-snippet-hook 'indent-according-to-mode)
(smart-operator-mode-on)
))
```

Comment: Can you `(setq debug-on-error t)` in your init files and then reproduce this error? You'll have a traceback then which will give us more information.

Comment: Nouful Ibrahim, thanks for tip. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after turning it off (smart-operator-mode-on)
I need to see how to solve smart-operator-mode-on

(setq debug-on-error t)  helps me to spot the error. Thanks Noufal.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error fixed by downloading the `smart-operator.el` file into a load-path and adding `require 'smart-operator'` before calling `smart-operator-mode-on`.